# Invalid redefinition error when passing a member enum variable to the class constructor

Tags: c++, eclipse, constructor, enums, arguments

First I should say the code compiles fine without error outside of eclipse. Ran into this problem moving a project into eclipse Juno, CDT 8.1, gcc version 4.6.3

```
//This example code works:

 1. class TestThis {
 2.  public:
 3.     enum NUMBER { one, two };
 4.     TestThis();
 5.     int populate(enum NUMBER n);
 6. };
```

```
//This generates an error "invalid redefinition of 'NUMBER'" at line 3 before compile:

 1. class TestThis {
 2. public:
 3.     enum NUMBER { one, two };
 4.     TestThis(enum NUMBER n);
 5.     int populate();
 6. };
```

Question: Is there a way to "fix" CDT to allow passing an enum to a constructor? or if not is there some other work-around for this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Say just this:

```
class TestThis
{
    enum NUMBER { one, two };
    TestThis(NUMBER n);
};
```

Your code is indeed re-declaring *another* `enum NUMBER`. This is no different from, say, `void (struct Foo x);`, which is actually a *declaration* of `struct Foo`.

**Update:** Multiple declarations are actually fine. Saying `enum` or `struct` again is possible, although probably not very pretty.

Comment: Actually my mistake for not mentioning that I tried TestThis(NUMBER n); TestThis(TestThis::NUMBER n); TestThis(enum TestThis::NUMBER n); TestThis(enum NUMBER n); all resulting in error. Yet I can use populate(enum NUMBER n); or populate(NUMBER n); or populate(TestThis::NUMBER n); or populate(enum TestThis::NUMBER n);

Comment: and I can add more functions that take "enum NUMBER n" as members and they don't cause the issue. i.e. test1(enum NUMBER n); test2(enum NUMBER n); and no problems - it just the constructor and like I said only in eclipse, the "enum <name> <variable>" function argument construct is valid C++. Its CDT that's off I think since like I said that code compiles fine from the command line.

Comment: @KeithStevens: You're right. Multiple declarations are not a problem. That said, if you don't repeat the `enum` key, you will also avoid the problem with your IDE. It's a bad habit that only marks you as a C programmer that's grudgingly been moved to a C++ project.

Comment: I don't mind removing the "enum" from the constructor argument in my bosses code, that has little to do with the issue at hand: CDT is flagging the enum declaration as a redefinition because an argument to the constructor is a variable of that type "enum" or no "enum". Yet it is all valid C++ code to pass a variable of an enum type as an argument to a constructor function. Sorry if I sound a little frustrated.

Comment: Not to argue but I want it made clear that removing "enum" from the argument construct does nothing at all in the IDE least of all avoiding the problem this post is about.

Comment: @KeithStevens: Oh, I see. Well, never mind then. Maybe file a bug report?

Answer (score 1):

I went to report the bug on eclipse CDT bugzilla and found it was already reported by Dominik Eichelberg (see Bug 385144) in July. Reading it gave me enough information for a work around. The issue does not occur if the enum variable is not the first argument to the constructor. Thank you everyone.